# How can I execute code after .onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with image preview before upload.
So I'm displaying the choosen files. It's working well.

But I'm stuck in a situation.
Foreach file on the "input file", the scripts tests if it's too small (smaller than 300px w:h).

If one of these files disobey this rule (must be width and height greater than 300px), the script has set an error var as true. And, after the "for" block, check if "error" is true or false.

I'm working in this scenario:

```
window.onload = function () {        
var fileUpload2 = document.getElementById("inputFileID");
    fileUpload2.onchange = function () {
        var error = false;
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = document.getElementById("divToShowPreview");
            dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            if(fileUpload2.files.length > 3) {
                alert('Only 3 files allowed!');
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload2.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = fileUpload2.files[i];
                    if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                        img.src = e.target.result;                        
                        img.onload = function() {
                            console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);
                            if(this.width >=300 && this.height >=300 )  {
                                dvPreview.appendChild(img);
                            } else {
                                error = true;
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    } else {
                        alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
                        dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                console.log(error);                  
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    };        
};
```

As you can see, the console.log(error) still shows FALSE!
How can I get this var set as true?

Thanks

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);`?

Comment: Please provide us a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the `img.onload` functions is asynchronously executed. therefore `console.log(error)` is executed before or between the `img.onload`

this can be proven by looking at the sequence of your `console.log`, that look something like:

```
false
300 300
200 300
```

to solve this problem, create a variable to count how many images have been load, then count it in every `img.onload`. when the count of image that has been load is equal to the uploaded image count, call a function to check if error exists. for example:

```
function imageError(){
    alert('image size to small');
}

window.onload = function () { 
    var fileUpload2 = document.getElementById("inputFileID");

    // add variables
    var imgLoaded = 0;       

    fileUpload2.onchange = function () {
        var error = false;
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = document.getElementById("divToShowPreview");
            dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            if(fileUpload2.files.length > 3) {
                alert('Only 3 files allowed!');
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload2.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = fileUpload2.files[i];
                    if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                        img.src = e.target.result;                        
                        img.onload = function() {

                            //increase the loaded img count
                            imgLoaded++;
                            console.log(imgLoaded); // another check to show the sequence of events

                            console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);
                            if(this.width >=300 && this.height >=300 )  {
                                dvPreview.appendChild(img);
                            } else {
                                error = true;
                            }

                            // call imageError if all image have been loaded and there is and error
                            if (imgLoaded == fileUpload2.files.length){
                                console.log(error) // just to check
                                if (error){
                                    imageError();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    } else {
                        alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
                        dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                //console.log(error);  // no need for this line
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    };        
};
```

Comment: Thanks folks! This solution worked well with just one change! You forgot to set "imgCount". So I used fileUpload2.files.length instead and worked ok! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to break your for when you find a error, so it will not perform the next verification.

```
...
} else {
  error = true;
  break;
}
...
```

Comment: If you want a error for each file, you have to implement an array of errors, where each array index is the same than the index in the array of files